# How to loop through variables in input box and save the HTML using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I am able to save file after doing something using puppeteer for one case if used directly. Now, I want to do this for variable 1 to 2000. For this, I even created a variable `i` but still it doesn't appear to work. Refer the code (comments on line 6, 14 and 22) below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  i = '1163'; //Created this variable to loop through numbers from 1 to 2000
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', (request) => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'image') request.abort();
    else request.continue();
  });
  await page.goto('http://example.com/Print_New.aspx');
  console.log(i);
  await page.$eval('#TextBox1', el => el.value = i); //Unable to use the variable
  const [response] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click('input[type="submit"]'),
  ]);
  const html = await page.content();
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile(`./out${i}.html`, html, function(err) { //Able to use the variable inside this. File is getting saved.
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: What page is this?

Answer (score 0):

In [`page.$eval()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1), the function argument is executed in the browser context, so you need to transfer variables from the Node.js context as arguments:

```js
await page.$eval('#TextBox1', (el, num) => el.value = num, i);
```